# Bash Separate values with commas then surround them with quotes in variable

Tags: bash, unix, sed

I have the below bash script:

```
STR1="US-1234 US-7685 TKT-008953"
#STR2= "${STR1// /,}"
STR2=`echo $STR1 | sed 's/ /,/g'`
echo $STR2
```

Current output: `US-1234,US-7685,TKT-008953`

Expected output: `'US-1234','US-9754','TKT-007643'`

Comment: see also: [Why is $(...) preferred over backticks?](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/082)

Comment: see also: https://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes. Run your script through http://shellcheck.net and it'll tell you about some of the issues.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With `bash` and its parameter expansion:

```
STR1="US-1234 US-7685 TKT-008953"
STR1="${STR1// /\',\'}"
STR1="${STR1/#/\'}"
echo "${STR1/%/\'}"
```

Output:

```
'US-1234','US-7685','TKT-008953'
```

Comment: you can use Wiktor's trick and do `STR2="'${STR1// /\',\'}'"`

Comment: Why not just `STR1="'${STR1// /\',\'}'"`? (just saw Sundeep mentioned that too - it'd be good to see it in the answer).

Answer (score 2):

You may use

```
STR2="'$(echo "$STR1" | sed "s/ /','/g")'"
```

See [online demo](https://ideone.com/9VxGMk)

All spaces are replaced with `','` using `sed "s/ /','/g"`, and the initial and trailing single quotes are added inside a double quoted string.

Answer (score 0):

```
$ echo 'US-1234 US-7685 TKT-008953' | sed -E "s/^|$/'/g; s/ /','/g"
'US-1234','US-7685','TKT-008953'

$ # can also use \x27 and continue using single quotes for the expression
$ echo 'US-1234 US-7685 TKT-008953' | sed -E 's/^|$/\x27/g; s/ /\x27,\x27/g'
'US-1234','US-7685','TKT-008953'
```

- `s/^|$/'/g` will add single quote at start/end of line
- `s/ /','/g` will replace space with `','`

Answer (score 0):

Use bash's global variable replacement to replace space with `','` and add quotes around it:

```
$ str2=\'${str1// /\',\'}\'
$ echo $str2
'US-1234','US-7685','TKT-008953'
```